# Why isn't componentDidCatch not preventing app crashes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am attempting to create a 'fail whale' page that pops up whenever the app crashes.

To do this I am attempting to use 'error boundaries' along with the new componentDidCatch lifecycle method.
https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

I am having no success so far and no matter what, the error crashes the app.

Here is the reproduction code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class InnerComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    throw new Error('why isn\'t this working')
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>Why is this rendering?</Text>
      </View>
      )
  }
}

class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = { hasError: false }
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, info) {
      this.setState({ hasError: true })
      console.log(error, info)
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.hasError) {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>Why is this not rendering?</Text>
          </View>
        )
      }
      return this.props.children
    }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <InnerComponent/>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a snack I made with the same issues:
https://snack.expo.io/BynlDr6-z

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: I just tested this and it works. Assure that you are running React v16.0 or later.

Comment: Have you tried running it in the snack? It's not working there for me....

Comment: Well, since your exact code is working for me but it isn't for you in Snack - it's probably a safe bet that Snack isn't configured properly ;) In other words, your code is fine.

Comment: Strange, Snack is using Expo SDK 23 which uses React 16. Can you please tell me which React and React Native version you are using?